# Roundoff of a number having 5 as last digit

Tags: python

I want to roundoff a number which has 5 in last. Python `round` function rounds the decimal number to ceil integer if decimal value >=5.

I want `round(30.195,2)` to output `30.19` but python gives `30.2`

Comment: What about `30.196`?  What is the expected out for this input?

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335744/3243159), please accept and like if it solved your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want `30.19` as an output of `round(30.195,2)`

Comment: remember to like and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
int(30.195*100)/100
```

`30.195` rounds to `30.2` because `0.005` is rounded up, resulting in `30.19 + 0.01 = 30.20` which is fine for rounding.

Note that my method above chops off the last digit, no rounding - which is what you would need to get the result you want. So both the below gives the same answer of `30.19`:

```
int(30.199*100)/100
int(30.191*100)/100
```

Here is the solution in function form:

```
def chop_off(val, places):
    return int(val*10**places)/10**places

print(chop_off(30.195,2))
```

In your case where you want to round down on 0.005 you can use this:

```
import math

def round_off(val, places):
    last_digit = val*10**(places+1)%10
    if last_digit > 5:
        return math.ceil(val*10**places)/10**places
    else:
        return math.floor(val*10**places)/10**places
    return int(val*10**places)/10**places

print(chop_off(30.194,2))  # 30.19
print(chop_off(30.195,2))  # 30.19
print(chop_off(30.196,2))  # 30.20
```

Comment: It would work but I have a list of 2000 floats and I want to round off all except numbers with 5 in last. So if I use your method I would have to check which number has 5 and which doesnt

Comment: Ok first clarify round off, do you mean floor, or only round? Secondly, is it a list or a numpy array, and are you open to using numpy arrays? Do you want to round all values, except if it ends with a 5 - then keep it? What happens if its 0.000005?

Comment: I want the number up to 2 decimal digits and I want to round off the numbers but in the case of 5 the `round` function gives ceil value and I need the same number in that case (up to 2 decimal digits). I am open to use numpy

Comment: ok so for `30.196` you want `30.20`, and for `30.195` you want `30.19` and for `30.194` you want `30.19`? May I ask why?

Answer (score 0):

you can subtract 0.001 from all the numbers you have and save in a separate list. that way, the round function will work as you wish. 30.195 will become 30.194 and rounded off to 30.19
30.196 will become 30.195 and rounded off to 30.20

if not, you can run a for loop and check if the 3rd decimal place is 5, then round it down manually, else use the builtin round function